# Vim completely broken, can not use

Tags: macos, vim, vim-plugin

Upon opening vim in my terminal, I receive this error

```
Error detected while processing CursorMoved Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>
6_Highlight_Matching_Pair:
```

It repeats multiple times upon launch vim, then I can access vim however any movement `(lkjh)` causes the error to occur more.

I have deleted my `.vimrc`, updated my vim via brew. Neither has had any affect, vim is my go to IDE because I have it set up with plug ins in a efficient way that I prefer for programming.

Can someone please help me figure out what is occurring? Also, possibly important info I recently ran a brew update to update everything in my package manager.

Comment: This is due to a bug in VIM; a patch will be distributed once https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/68064 is merged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside vim you can try using `:scriptnames` to get the list of loaded scripts and determine what files could be causing the issue. You can also check if vim can load without loading any additional scripts by launching with `vim -u NONE`.

Comment: Using the script names suggestion I found the files in my /usr/ dir that were still activate, removed them, and re implemented my vimrc which brought my vim back to a working state. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Delete all files under ~/.vim/plugged to boot normally.
Command: rm -rf ~/.vim/plugged